# javascript... typewriter ticker... how can I change the line size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Anyone have any ideas how to change the length of one line with this ticker... I found this on the internet. I use it because it run's off a list which I can echo php data to... It works great but I would like to increase the length by about 10 characters?

```
<script>

(function($)
{
$.fn.Ticker = function(options)
{
    var defaults = {

        // This is how long the text remains
        pause: 4000,

        // Transition in
        fadeIn: 200,

        // Transition out
        fadeOut: 200,

        // Pause between displaying each item when fading between items.
        delay: 10,

        // Next news item typed out one character at a time. If false item will fade in. (boolean)
        typewriter: true,

        // Time to type each character if using the typewriter effect (integer, normal typewriter speed is 35 I placed it at 30
        speed: 57,

        // Character to use to mimic a computer cursor if using the typewriter effect.
        cursor: '_'
    };

    // Merge default options with user options
    var opts = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    return $(this).each(function()
    {
        var list = $(this), typewriter = {}, interval;

        // Activate ticker and display first item
        list
            .addClass('ticker-active')
            .children(':first')
            .css('display', 'block');

        function changeItem()
        {
            var item = list.children(':first'),
                next = item.next(),
                copy = item.clone();

            clearTimeout(interval);

            // Append copy of current item to bottom of list
            $(copy)
                .css('display', 'none')
                .appendTo(list);

            // Fade current item out, remove from DOM then animate the next item
            item.fadeOut(opts.fadeOut, function()
            {
                $(this).remove();

                // Animate
                if (opts.typewriter)
                {
                    typewriter.string = next.text();

                    next
                        .text('')
                        .css('display', 'block');

                    typewriter.count = 0;
                    typewriter.timeout = setInterval(type, opts.speed);
                }
                else
                {
                    next
                        .delay(opts.delay)
                        .fadeIn(opts.fadeIn, function ()
                        {
                            setTimeout(changeItem, opts.pause);
                        });
                }
            });
        }

        function type()
        {
            typewriter.count++;

            var text =  typewriter.string.substring(0, typewriter.count);

            if (typewriter.count >= typewriter.string.length)
            {
                clearInterval(typewriter.timeout);
                setTimeout(changeItem, opts.pause);
            }
            else if (opts.cursor)
            {
                text+= ' ' + opts.cursor;
            }

            list
                .children(':first')
                .text(text);
        }

        // Test there are more items to display then start ticker
        if (list.find('li').length > 1 )
        {
            interval = setTimeout(changeItem, opts.pause);
        }
    });
 };

 $('.ticker').Ticker();

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see anything about line length--you sure it's not just the size of the element that's tickering?

Comment: I think you're right. So the question would be changing the size of element and how it's done? Through css? Sorry I'm a python programmer, this is all new to me.